# Unable to install/run grunt 0.4 (Win 7)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm new to grunt and I've just tried to install it following the instructions on http://gruntjs.com/getting-started.

First I install grunt-cli :

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

In AppData/Roaming I can see these folder and files:

```
|_ node_modules/
  |_ grunt-cli/
|_ grunt
|_ grund.cmd
```

Then in my project directory I run:

```
npm install grunt
```

Which creates:

```
|_ node_modules/
  |_ grunt/
```

But if I try to run grunt, I get an error message saying that **"grunt is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"**. I'm simply trying to run `grunt init:jquery` for a start, as explained here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/meeting-grunt-the-build-tool-for-javascript/

Comment: FYI, that tutorial looks like it's based on Grunt 0.3. The init task is not part of the core plus quite a few other changes.

Comment: Indeed it is, as I've come to realize later. Better to stick with the official Grunt documentation, which is quite clear and up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add path to "npm" stuff to your PATH environment variable: (Right click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables)

Like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;*C:\<path_to_node>\node\npm*
```

and then restart cmd

Comment: Isn't latest grunt version automatically takes care of unless until any write permission issue?

Comment: Well, you will not be able to run grunt that easy in the first place if it's not in the path, are you? It's up to Node.js to handle PATH.

Comment: True @mishik, I think it does work like charm on OSX but one has to do manual entry on windows and I am on OSX luckily.

Answer (score 2):

Referring this link http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
grunt is no longer installed globally
so run

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```